# C++ ptr_fun not finding void parameterized functions

Tags: c++, function

I tried using the std::ptr_fun to wrap my function, but when I try to wrap a function with void parameter and bool return type I end up with an error:

code:

```
std::function<bool()> cr = std::not1(std::ptr_fun(&funct1));
```

function:

```
bool funct1()      
{                  
    return false;     
}
```

the error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'ptr_fun(bool (*)())'

but whenever I change the parameter to int, the problem seems to go away.

how do I wrap a function with a void parameter?

Comment: `ptr_fun` is deprecated. Use `std::bind`.

Comment: i can't, my schools compiler does not support C++11 yet, and they're being stubborn about updating it.

Comment: `boost::bind` then? Heh.

Comment: @MauriceRodriguez: If you don't support C++11, then how do you expect `std::function` to work?!

Comment: @KerrekSB im practicing on my own PC, it supports C++11,

Answer (score 3):

`std::ptr_fun` only works on unary functions: functions with exactly one parameter.

`bool funct1();` is not a unary function, it is a nullary function.  There is no such thing as a void parameter.  The syntax `bool funct1(void);` inherited from C is just a strange way of saying there are no parameters at all.